# VIM: swap columns separated by colon

Tags: vim

How do I swap multiple columns separated by ':' in VIM editor?
(wanted order is 2, 3, 4, 1, (...))

eg.
1:2:3:4:5:6 -> 2:3:4:1:5:6

edit: I need to swap more than one line at once.

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
:s/\v(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*)/\2:\3:\4:\1:\5:\6
```

Comment: Thank you. And what if there is always 5 columns and only sometimes more (5+)? I suppose something like: :s/\v(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*)/\2:\3:\4:\1:\5 (this doesnt work)?

Comment: cool! (+1) @Allemis, to deal with more than 5 we need non greedy repetition (please see my answer).

Comment: I swapped two fields using :%s/\v(.*):(.*)/\2:\1

Answer (score 2):

If there is awk available on your system, I would do this with external awk, it looks more straightforward than the regex way:

```
%!awk -F: -v OFS=":" '{print $2,$3,$4,$1,$5,$6}'
```

Also there is a plugin called "exchange", it may make it easier as well.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work - the columns to swap are different lengths (5 - ...), I think that this would work only if there were 6 columns only, if I am not mistaken...

Comment: @Allemis the awk line is easy to extend. say, you have 200 columns and just want to exchange 3 and 6, you can `%!awk -F: -v OFS=":" '{t=$3;$3=$6;$6=t}7'`

Comment: @JJoao a non-zero number in awk does default action: `print`, you can use 1,2,3,4...1000... the same

Comment: I know, i was just wondering if there was some underground subliminar reason ☺...

Comment: right index finger (7) v.s. left little finger (1) ?@JJoao

Comment: I knew it! ( 1 vs 7 = improvement on agility and skills)

Answer (score 1):

In order to deal with more than 5 fields, the non-greedy repetition operator (`.{-}` instead of `.*`) should be used:

```
:s/\v(.{-}):(.{-}):(.{-}):(.{-}):/\2:\3:\4:\1:/
```